# Retorno de parametro al usar nombre de objeto

Tags: java, poo

Estoy haciendo unas cuantas clases en Java. Me preguntaba si es posible retornar un atributo específico cuando una instancia en llamada, por ejemplo.

```java
public class Num{
    private int num;
    public Num(int n){
        this.num = n;
    }
}
```

quiero que cuando llame a una instancia de Num, me devuelva el atributo num de esa instancia.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(){
        Num a = new Num(4);
        int b = a + 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi opinión, no es posible que la instancia de la clase como tal devuelva el valor, sin embargo, podrías agregar un método get dentro de la clase

```
public int getNum(){
    return this.num;
}
```

Y dentro de la suma, ultilizar el método que se creó dentro de la clase:

```
int b = a.getNum() +5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de la clase `NUm` debes instanciar los metodos getter y setter de la siguiente manera:

```
   public class Num{
      private int num;
      public Num(int n){
          this.num = n;
      }

      public int getNum() {
         return num;
      }

      public void setNum(int num) {
          this.num = num;
      }
 }
```

Para generar los getter y setter de forma automática en tu código lo puedes hacer con `ALT+Shift+S` y hacer click en `Generate Guetters and Setters`

A continuación cuando llames a la instancia de NUM

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(){
        Num a = new Num(4);
        int b = a.getNum() + 5;
    }
}
```